# After nginx installation cannot login in to my site's UI

Tags: post, nginx, php

so there is my problem: I've switched from apache to nginx, installed php-fpm and everything seems to be okay except one thing - I can no longer login through my webpage login form. I mean - when i type wrong credentials - It fetches and says "Bad details". But when I try to login with good details - page just refreshes without any sign. nginx error log doesn't show anything special, same as php-fpm log.

This is my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  6;

events {
worker_connections    1000;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
types_hash_bucket_size 64;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

sendfile        off;
tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  4;


server {
    listen       80;
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    server_name  diamond-ptp.com;
    index index.php index.html;
 location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }


  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/login.php /login.php;
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
         include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

There is my phpinfo(); : http://diamond-ptp.com/info.php

It's writter there: _SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET , shouldn't it be POST if I use post method in my login form?

So I wonder maybe it's something $_POST related? Because overall PHP works good. Or maybe something with caching? Anyone has suggestions?

Comment: Have you made sure your `session` folder is owned by `nginx`? By default it's normally owned by apache. You may need to run something (via `sudo`) like: `chown -R user:nginx /var/lib/php/session`, replacing the path with your distro's path, and "user" with the appropriate user (usually `root`)

Comment: You saved my day man! Thanks! Definately that issue!

Comment: Great, glad to help, moved this to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving from comments to here, make sure to check your `session` folder. By default, it's normally owned by apache, making logins seemingly "fail".

To fix this, you'll want to re-own your sessions folder, running something like this (via `sudo`, normally):

```
chown -R user:nginx /var/lib/php/session
```

You'll want to replace that path (`/var/lib/php`) with your distro's session path, and the user (`user` in `user:nginx`) with the proper user (usually `root`)

Comment: It works for me on Ubuntu:  chown www-data:www-data -R /var/lib/php/sessions

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue regarding permissions:

```
chown -R user:nginx /var/lib/php/session
```

This command worked out and helped me!